# Using Entity Framework how can I do a search on phone number ignoring spaces?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

```
var Data = (from Client in _context.Client.Include(c => c.ClientType)
            select Client);

Data = Data.Where(m => ...  || (m.MobilePhone != null && String.Concat(m.MobilePhone.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))) == search)).ToList();
```

This works if the `mobilephone` is not null but errors out with a null reference exception if `phonenumber` is null.

I have added the `m.MobilePhone != null` condition but it seems like the normal `AND` order is not being applied here so it doesn't stop the error.

I know I could convert to a list and then filter it but the number of results is to big for that.

Any suggestions about how to fix the error or another approach?

Comment: Use m.MobilePhone.Trim() ignoring spaces while search.

Comment: I want to ignore all spaces even those in the middle of the string. A search for 123456789 should return results the have a phone number of 123 456 789 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My above code is correct. It is working after an upgrade from EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver 2.1.3 to 2.1.14

Answer (score 0):

Use !string.IsNullOrEmpty for filter out null and empty space

```
var Data = (from Client in _context.Client.Include(c => c.ClientType)
select Client);

Data = Data.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.MobilePhone) && m.MobilePhone == search).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it to remove all spaces in the string like this?
[image]

You can also use regular expressions to remove all spaces in the string.

```
string str = "123 456 789";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "");
```